# How can I patch a large hole in a particle board with something removable?

Tags: wood, sealing, smell

I live in an apartment building on the second floor, and there is a strong smell of cigarette smoke coming through a vanity. After removing the drawers, I saw that there was a roughly 5x12" hole sawed out of the wood on the inside of the vanity to allow access to the shower water pipes. Unfortunately I believe the odors are coming through this hole, even though it's covered with a piece of cardboard and duct tape.

Is there any way I can patch this hole with something that would stop the smell, but still be removable so that the pipes can still be accessed easily?

Comment: It's unlikely that a substantial amount of odor is coming through that hole if it's patched in such a way as to stop air flow. I'd be looking elsewhere.

Comment: I thought that the cardboard would be enough as well, but I can't find any other place that could possibly be letting in air. Any hints on trying to identify a possible place? I am trying to think of a way that would make it easy to discover leaks in such an a awkward space

Comment: I've already used the Great Stuff expanding foam to seal the gaps where the sink pipes go behind the drywall.

Comment: Air leakage is tough. It could be a matter of there being a hundred tiny leaks between your apartment and others.

Comment: You should really try plastic rather than cardboard. Cardboard will absorb some of the components in smoke and start to smell itself.

Comment: Hmm, is there a specific type of plastic you would recommend? I was wondering if cardboard was a bad idea... and would clear packing tape be a better sealant than duct tape?